# Does gradle-gae-plugin support datastore callbacks

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I am in the process of convincing my colleagues to use gradle and gradle-gae-plugin in order to build & test our GAE project.

Today I noticed that there are hands on stuff to do in Eclipse in order to support "Datastore callbacks".

Se https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks#Using_Callbacks_With_Eclipse

How does this work with gradle-gae-plugin?

a) By magic? 
b) Not at all! 
c) I have to do something?

Comment: Did you try it out with the plugin without any particular configuration?

Comment: Yes and i get this output in the console.

SEVERE: DATASTORE CALLBACKS NOT ENABLED, THIS APPLICATION VERSION WILL NOT WORK
jul 16, 2013 6:44:01 FM se.maginteractive.davinci.DavinciServlet init
SEVERE: This is most likely due to the application built using incorrect Elipcse settings, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks#Using_Callbacks_With_Eclipse

Comment: And the java compile says:

:compileJava
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'com.google.appengine.tools.compilation.DatastoreCallbacksProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning

Comment: The AppEngine documentation doesn't really say what Eclipse sets under the covers. From the second error message it sounds like you have to tell the compiler to change to the source compatibility to 1.7. This is just a guess but try to add `sourceCompability = '1.7'` to your build script.